# How I can require script from data folder

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to load js file from page and require it in background page.

I try use two copy in lib and in data folder, but have problem with review.

I can load it from lib folder in page, but it uncomfortable for other browsers.

I can load it via loader:

```
mono = require('toolkit/loader').main(require('toolkit/loader').Loader({
    paths: {
        'sdk/': 'resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/',
        'data/': self.data.url('js/'),
        '': 'resource:///modules/'
    },
    name: self.name,
    prefixURI: 'resource://'+self.id.slice(1, -1)+'/'
}), "data/mono");
```

But have problem with:

```
require('net/xhr').XMLHttpRequest
```

I try use for options it, but have same problems.

```
require('@loader/options')
```

Now I use it, but all require objects I send via arguments.

Have ideas?

*upd*
Now I use this code, it allow require modules and don't store it in memory, as I think. But need to declare all modules previously.

```
mono = require('toolkit/loader').main(require('toolkit/loader').Loader({
    paths: {
        'data/': self.data.url('js/')
    },
    name: self.name,
    prefixURI: 'resource://'+self.id.slice(1, -1)+'/',
    globals: {
        console: console,
        _require: function(path) {
            switch (path) {
                case 'sdk/timers':
                    return require('sdk/timers');
                case 'sdk/simple-storage':
                    return require('sdk/simple-storage');
                case 'sdk/window/utils':
                    return require('sdk/window/utils');
                case 'sdk/self':
                    return require('sdk/self');
                default:
                    console.log('Module not found!', path);
            }
        }
    }
}), "data/mono");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this blogpost from erikvold addresses the problem you are facing: http://work.erikvold.com/jetpack/2014/09/23/jp-pro-tip-reusing-js.html

Comment: It work only for NPM packages or other libs. But it don't work if I need load js from data folder. Problem don't have solution, because all require to declare when build xpi.

Comment: user84531: the solution for your problem, is as described to place the js library in the lib folder, so it can get loaded by modules. You can then load the same file like a file in the data folder.

Comment: humanoid: Yes I write about it "I can load it from lib folder in page, but it uncomfortable for other browsers.".